# How do I CPYJOBJS *all from systema to systemb

Tags: ibm-midrange, job-scheduling

How do I CPYJOBJS *all from systema to systemb.

System A is V7.1
System B is V7.3

I'm guess I'n not sure how to format the command.  I've tried.

CPYJOBJS FROMJOB(*ALL)
         TOJOB(*RMTLOCNAME)
         RMTLOCNAME('10.1.53.233')

And I get error on RMTLOCNAME.  I like other mortals don't always understand the help text.

Specify the network identifier and the name of the
remote location associated with the system.  Specify
these values using the format nnnnnnnn.cccccccc where 
nnnnnnnn is the network identifier and cccccccc is the
remote location name.

Answer (score 4):

I do not have that command on my system, but it looks like it is looking for an `SNA` address rather than an `IP` address. You can execute `DSPNETA` to find the Local Network ID, and the Current System Name for each machine. The Local Network ID will likely be the same, and may be APPN. You will have to have your `SNA` network configured properly to make this work. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahj/rzahjovr.htm

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1017913   Actually this was quite painless.  Gave you the answer for effort.  It autmatically upgraded the files.